# node.js framework for stomp-client/stompit

Tags: node.js, express, activemq-classic, hapi.js

I am going to use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompit or https://www.npmjs.com/package/stomp-client to subscribe to ActiveMQ. My question is, is there a node.js framework that I can use with it (e.g. Hapi, Express) ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to start a server to use these packages.

Just include them in any JS file, configure them and they are ready to be used. Much like it is explained in [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompit) itself.

Or if you want to include them in one of your express application, create a js file, and include it in your application.